# Compare Object in Javascript and list out the differences

Tags: javascript, object, comparison

I want to compare 2 objects using javascript and list out the differences between the objects. I see there are libraries deep-object-diff which can let me do something similar, but I am looking for something which even lists the values changed from something to null or null to something. Whenever I try to use any  library, I am able to list out the changes, but whenever I try to compare null with anything, it returns null.

So, if I have 2 object like

```
a: {name: null, date: 12/28/2017, dept: sales}
b: {name: john, date: 12/28/2017, dept: technology}
```

The resultant object should be

```
c: {name: john, dept: technology}
```

I am not looking for deep array object comparison as of now.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you add the code you've tried ([mcve]) by editing your question.

Comment: Loop over one of the objects, comparing each property to the corresponding property in the other object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this.

The right is compared to the left object, so if a property is missing from the right it will be wrapped in `Missing` if the property is missing from the left it will be wrapped in `Extra`

```js
const left = {name: null, date: '12/28/2017', dept: 'sales', one: 'leftExtra', three: 'leftExtra2'} 
const right = {name: 'john', date: '12/28/2017', dept: 'technology', two: 'rightExtra'}

const defined = thing => typeof thing !== 'undefined'

const compare = (left, right) => {
  const leftKeys = Object.keys(left)
  const rightKeys = Object.keys(right)
  const keys = Array.from(new Set([...leftKeys, ...rightKeys]))
  
  return keys.reduce((comparison, key) => {
    if (defined(left[key]) && !defined(right[key])) {
      comparison.missing[key] = left[key]
    }
    else if (!defined(left[key]) && defined(right[key])) {
      comparison.extra[key] = right[key]
    }
    else if (left[key] !== right[key]) {
      comparison.different[key] = right[key]
    }
    else {
      comparison.same[key] = left[key]
    }
    return comparison
  }, { same: {}, different: {}, missing: {}, extra: {} })
}

console.log(
  compare(left, right)
)
```

```html
<script src="https://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/KyQQmL.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot synthet1c. I used the snippet you explained above and it worked for me.